# How to update data from column i row 2 to column j row 1 in R dataframe?

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion

I have a column i with 12 data points. I want to copy column i, row 2 to column j row 1. Repeat this pattern for the rest of the rows. Then assign column j row 12 column i row 1.
So, if column i went from 1 to 12. Column j would go from 2, 3,4...12, 1.
The last bit seems easy to do, but I'm struggling with the for loop for the first part. I'm not sure if that's the best approach or not.

```
col.i <- rnorm(12,5,2)
df <- data.frame(col.i)
for(i in df$col.i){df$col.j <- df$col.i[i+1]}
Edit: It picks a random row from col.i and duplicates it in column j
df$col.j[12] <- df$col.i[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dplyr approach, its a bit hacky as it assumes your data has no na's by using the deault option, and that you always want the first value in col.i to be the last value in col.j.

```
library(dplyr)
answr <- df %>% 
  mutate(col.j = lead(col.i, default = col.i[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not an easy trick like this one, without any loop:

```
df$col.j<-c(df[2:nrow(df),"col.i"],df[1,"col.i"])
df$col.j
 [1] 3.521080 7.407137 4.366953 3.987189 2.098757 3.460251 6.249959 7.353239 6.065238
[10] 5.105430 5.937099 4.999444
> df
      col.i    col.j
1  4.999444 3.521080
2  3.521080 7.407137
3  7.407137 4.366953
4  4.366953 3.987189
5  3.987189 2.098757
6  2.098757 3.460251
7  3.460251 6.249959
8  6.249959 7.353239
9  7.353239 6.065238
10 6.065238 5.105430
11 5.105430 5.937099
12 5.937099 4.999444
```

You can paste data starting from the second to the end and then add the first element.

Comment: I tried this with a very similar structure in my actual data and I run into this error "Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 12 rows. x Assigned data has 2 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled."

Comment: My original data set has several other columns. But as long as I specify the column name, it shouldn't matter right?

Comment: Yes, number of columns doesn't metter in this case

Comment: Are you able to replicate the error with a sample dataset?

Comment: the first element is saved as a list with 11 elements and the second as a one. Combining the list makes it a list of 2. Any other method?

Comment: try to parse lists with function unlist before binding them together.