# How to update data from column i row 2 to column j row 1 but grouped by two variables (dplyr) in a R dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, recursion, dplyr

I have two columns: sites (3 sites) and month (Jan - Mar) where I sampled in each month. For each month I have corresponding values in column i. I want to copy column i, row 2 to column j row 1. Then assign column j row 3 column i row 1. Repeat this pattern for the rest of the rows for each site. So, if column i went from 1 to 18. Column j would go from 2  3  1  5  6  4  8  9  7 11 12 10 14 15 13 17 18 13.  I tried to modify the code from an answer for a similar problem I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66029548/6820344) using dplyr. I tried to use the group_by function in dplyr so that it would loop back again, but the function is operating on the entire column.

```
library(dplyr)
col.site <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6)
col.month <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar")
col.i <- c(1:18)
df <- data.frame(col.site,col.month, col.i)
df <- df %>% group_by(col.month,col.site) %>% 
             mutate(col.j = lead(col.i, default = col.i[1]))

col.j
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  1

What I expected col.j:
[1]  2  3  1  5  6  4  8  9  7 11 12 10 14 15 13 17 18 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should only `group_by` `col.site` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(col.site) %>% 
  mutate(col.j = lead(col.i, default = first(col.i)))

#   col.site col.month col.i col.j
#      <dbl> <chr>     <int> <int>
# 1        1 Jan           1     2
# 2        1 Feb           2     3
# 3        1 Mar           3     1
# 4        2 Jan           4     5
# 5        2 Feb           5     6
# 6        2 Mar           6     4
# 7        3 Jan           7     8
# 8        3 Feb           8     9
# 9        3 Mar           9     7
#10        4 Jan          10    11
#11        4 Feb          11    12
#12        4 Mar          12    10
#13        5 Jan          13    14
#14        5 Feb          14    15
#15        5 Mar          15    13
#16        6 Jan          16    17
#17        6 Feb          17    18
#18        6 Mar          18    16
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, col.j := shift(col.i, type = 'lead', fill = first(col.i)), col.site]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(col.site) %>%
   mutate(col.j = c(col.i[-1], col.i[1]))
```

-output

```
#     col.site col.month col.i col.j
#      <dbl> <chr>     <int> <int>
# 1        1 Jan           1     2
# 2        1 Feb           2     3
# 3        1 Mar           3     1
# 4        2 Jan           4     5
# 5        2 Feb           5     6
# 6        2 Mar           6     4
# 7        3 Jan           7     8
# 8        3 Feb           8     9
# 9        3 Mar           9     7
#10        4 Jan          10    11
#11        4 Feb          11    12
#12        4 Mar          12    10
#13        5 Jan          13    14
#14        5 Feb          14    15
#15        5 Mar          15    13
#16        6 Jan          16    17
#17        6 Feb          17    18
#18        6 Mar          18    16
```